# bugs due to pyspark lazy evalution

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, lazy-evaluation

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf


conf = SparkConf().setAppName("Ark API Stats")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)


a = sc.parallelize([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
count = [2,4]
array = [a.filter(lambda x: x < y) for  y in count]

results = sc.union(array).collect()
print(results)
```

Above code will return `[1,2,3,1,2,3]`, whereas what I want is `[1,1,2,3]`.
It seems in `a.filter(lambda x: x < y)`, the y will always be `4` as the last number in the `count`. 
Any solutions?